# Response encoding filled with diamond characters with question marks. Express, Axis, and Node

Tags: node.js, api, encoding, response

I'm currently using express, node, and prisma to create a server but whenever I request a GET request to another API using axios, the response data contains diamond characters with questions marks. I've specified the charset and responseEncoding to utf-8 but that didn't solve anything. Any suggestions?

```
import axios from "axios";

export function xola() {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://sandbox.xola.com/api/categories",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "X-API-VERSION": "2017-06-10",
    },
    charset: "utf8",
    responseEncoding: "utf8",
  };

  axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

[image: diamonds with question marks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to check version of your `axios` library.

Looks like the latest [version 1.2.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios/v/1.2.0) of `axios` has changes in the response decompression logic and it doesn't work if server does not set the response content-length header. If that's a case - just temporary downgrade to the last [stable version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios/v/1.1.3) `1.1.3` i.e.:

```
npm i axios@1.1.3
```

### UPDATE

Looks like adding a header `'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'` fixes an issue without a need to downgrade

Comment: Thank you! This ended up solving my issue.